# How to write file path into txt.file?

Tags: java, file

I am writing simple program that is looking for file and if it exists, writes his path to txt file. If not, program is freezed for 1 minute. My problem is that file path is not being printed into txt file when searched file exists. I think it is something wrong with try block. I do not know where the problem is. How can i solve it?

```
public class FileScanner {
public void scanFolder() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //tworzenie pliku logu
    File log = new File("C:/Users/mateu/OneDrive/Pulpit/log.txt");
    if (!log.exists()) {
        log.createNewFile();
    }

    //obiekt zapisujacy nazwy i sciezki plikow do logu
    PrintWriter printIntoLog = new PrintWriter(log);


    while (true) {
        //podanie sciezki szukanego pliku
        System.out.println("Input file's directory you are looking for: ");
        String path = input.nextLine();
        //utworzenie obiektu do danego pliku
        File searchedFile = new File(path);

        //sprawdzenie czy plik istnieje- jesli tak to zapisuje do logu jego sciezke i usuwa go
        try{
            if (searchedFile.exists()) {
                printIntoLog.println(searchedFile.getPath());
                //searchedFile.delete();
            }else{
                throw new MyFileNotFoundException("Searching stopped for 1 minute.");
            }
        }catch(MyFileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is merely a guess, but I'm pretty sure you have to close a printwriter for the results to show up.

Comment: In `while` loop open and close the PrintWriter. Make sure you `append` the text instead of creating new file every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should close the `PrintWriter` reference before finishing execution. It's an enforced practice to close a file after read/write on it.

If you are using Java +7 you can use  the fancy way with`try-with-resources` syntax

````
```java
try (PrintWriter printIntoLog = new PrintWriter(log)) {
   while (true) { 
      ....
   }
}
```
````

With older versions you can use `try-finally` syntax

```
try {
  while(true) {
     ...
  }
} finally {
   printIntoLog.close();
}
```

See

[Java – Try with Resources](https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources)